# CKEditor not showing with Sonata Formatter (Sonata Admin Bundle)

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm having troubles using the [Sonata Formatter Bundle](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsonata-project.org%2Fbundles%2Fformatter%2Fmaster%2Fdoc%2Findex.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFBDlzAZFQk_PUzLIZqZZZ4nEbNMA).

In my **config.yml** I have the following (amongst other stuff):

```
imports:
    - { resource: sonata.yml }

twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

    #sonata
    form:
        resources:
            # ...
            - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

In my **sonata.yml** file I have:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        # Your other blocks
        sonata.formatter.block.formatter:

sonata_formatter:
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #        - sonata.media.formatter.twig #keep this commented unless you are using media bundle.


        text:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.text
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #        - sonata.media.formatter.twig


        rawhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #        - sonata.media.formatter.twig


        richhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #        - sonata.media.formatter.twig


        twig:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
            extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions

    ckeditor:
        templates:
            browser: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:browser.html.twig'
            upload: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:upload.html.twig'

ivory_ck_editor:
    configs:
        default:
            language:  '%locale%'
            toolbar: standard

sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:                 DXEenhanaBundle:Admin:standard_layout.html.twig
```

I've added the needed CSS and JS to my **standard_layout.html.twig** file and they are correctly loaded.

In my Admin file I have the following:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Applicant Name'))
    ->add('contacts', 'sonata_formatter_type', array(
        'event_dispatcher' => $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getEventDispatcher(),
        'format_field'   => 'contacts',
        'source_field'   => 'contacts',
        'source_field_options'      => array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'span10', 'rows' => 7)
        ),
        'ckeditor_context' => 'default',
        'listener'       => true,
        'target_field'   => 'contacts',
        'label' => 'Contacts'
    ))
    ...
```

I see a textarea but no ckeditor in my textarea, what am I missing?
This is what I see in my browser:
[image]

I'm also not getting any console errors or other errors ... .

Comment: This probably might not be the case but have you done this in your document onload? `CKEDITOR.replace( 'productEdit_PO_Note' );`

Comment: Why do I have to do that, I can't find it in the documentation...

Comment: Please check http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation

Comment: my id is dynamic so I can't set it by id ..

Comment: You have to set it somehow. Its the requirement of CKEditor. Could you also add your twig and controller code?

Comment: Just add an extra class `ckeditor`. Latest version of CKEditor replaces by default all elements containing that class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to overwrite the admin layout.html.twig template as described in the section [**Sonata Admin Integration** of SonataFormatterBundle Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html#sonata-admin-integration).

Create a new template file `app\Resources\SonataAdminBundle\views\layout.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/skins/sonata/style.css') }}" type="text/css"
      media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/style.css') }}"
      type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/style.css') }}" type="text/css"
      media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/style.css') }}" type="text/css"
      media="all"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/ivoryckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/vendor/markitup-markitup/markitup/jquery.markitup.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and update your **config.yml** with:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig
```

Comment: In Symfony4 you can override bundle template by placing it in `templates/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/standard_layout.html.twig`

Answer (score 3):

It may be a bit too late for you, but I had the same problem. I had to add a "ckeditor" class on the field:

```
->add('htmlContent', 'sonata_simple_formatter_type', array('format' => 'richhtml', 'attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')))
```

And that made it work

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and all the solutions here don't fix it. Adding the 'ckeditor' class messes it up with SonataNewsBundle.

Answer (score 1):

Since SonataAdmin#v0.3 you can add assets in config file. [Formatter Docs](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/3-x/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html#sonata-admin-integration)

`sonata_admin.yaml`

```
sonata_admin:
    assets:
        extra_javascripts:
            # ...
            - bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/vendor/markitup-markitup/markitup/jquery.markitup.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/set.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/set.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/set.js

        extra_stylesheets:
            # ...
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/skins/sonata/style.css
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/style.css
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/style.css
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/style.css
```